# Field for Validator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activemodel

If I have some CustomValidator, and following validation in model

```
validates :fieldname, :custom => true
```

How can I access `:fieldname` or `true`? Validator only takes object (`def validate(record)`) and I can't use EachValidator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I know: `self.options[:attributes]`